# Troubles with express and socket.io sessions

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I seem to not be able to share sessions between express and socket io . It works when on localhost but not when on my server. There is something I am missing.

The data I store in socket.handshake.session ('age' here) is not saved on the express side.

My app.js goes like this:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');


var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
var sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  name: 'sessionId',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
  // store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redisClient, ttl: 86400 }),
});
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.set("sessionMW", sessionMiddleware);


module.exports = app;
```

My bin\www goes like this:

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('testserver:server');
var http = require('http');
var sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


var session = app.get("sessionMW")

io.use(sharedsession(session, {autosave:true}));

server.listen(port);
```

I then have a serverEvent.js that goes like this:

```
var serverEvents = module.exports = function(io){
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
...
...
...
 socket.on('updateAgeSession', function (message) {

        socket.handshake.session.age = "18";    
        socket.handshake.session.save();
         console.log(socket.handshake.session);
      })
})
}
```

And finaly I have this index.js for my routes:

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {

    // show the home page (will also have our login links)
    app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

        res.cookie('mycookies', 'express');
        res.cookie('age', req.session.age);
        cookie1= req.cookies;

        console.log(req.session);
        console.log(req.sessionID);

        console.log(req.sessionStore.sessions);

        if (req.session.views) {
            req.session.views++;
            console.log(req.session.views);
          } else {
            req.session.views = 1
            console.log(req.session.views);
          }

          if(req.session.age){
              console.log("OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
          } else {
            console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
          }

        res.render('homePage'); // ejs template 
    });
}
```

So my problem is that after I enter that Im over 18 when I refresh the page , the req.session.age will be undefined, but only when my code runs on server, it does work on localhost. I dont get it. 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might have got the same problem I had, here is the solution :

I also have a client side code that goes like this :

```
var socket = io.connect("http://ip:3000");
var globalVar = [];
// Sent on connection/searchValidatedFromClient by server
socket.on("loadHomePageFromServer", function(message) {
...}
```

Problem was `io.connect("http://ip:3000");`.

By changing it to `io.connect("http://namesite.com");` or `io.connect("http://ip:80");`, it works!